# Referencing class properties dynamically

Tags: php, laravel

```
for ($e = 1; $e <= 10; $e++)
{
    $edd = Setting::where('id', '=', $e)->update([
      'nama' => $request->nama1,
      'isi'  => $request->isi1,
    ]);
}
```

How can I dynamically reference class properties within the `for` loop? I want to reference `nama1` and `isi1` up to `nama10` and `isi10` on the `$request` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
for ($e = 1; $e <= 10; $e++)
{
    $edd = Setting::where('id', '=', $e)->update([
      'nama' => $request->{"nama$e"},
      'isi'  => $request->{"isi$e"},
    ]);
}
```

For more readability, you might want to do this:

```php
$request->{"nama{$e}"} // Notice the inner braces around $e
```